# Can a Visual Studio 2008 custom tool be passed additional parameters from the custom tool property grid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vs-extensibility

Can a Visual Studio 2008 [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166817.aspx) [tool](http://www.drewnoakes.com/snippets/WritingACustomCodeGeneratorToolForVisualStudio/) be passed additional parameters from the custom tool property grid in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. You'd fix this by adding the custom tool as a custom build rule instead. The (built-in) build rule for C++ files causes the property sheets for C++ files; the build rule for IDL files causes those property sheets. Your own custom build rule can define its own property sheets.

Comment: C# is the language, not the IDE. So, in Visual Studio, there is a built-in build rule for C# (.cs) files.

Comment: Ok yes, that was a stupid question. The real question would be how do I add custom build rules from within visual studio?

Comment: Hmm - seems that the .Net term is a custom build *action*, not rule. And this is done behind the scenes through MSBuild. C++ is the odd one out.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse parameters by using the CustomToolNamespace setting.

It is rather much code to read it out though.

See an example `GetResourcesNamespace()` in ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx.cs in ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx found at http://sites.google.com/site/dmytrokryvko/